# Upload Image Folder zip for Image of products in Magento 2.1

Tags: import, magento-2.1, magento-2.0, upload

I want to upload products image folder (Zip format) from Admin ,

The uploaded folder suppose to go **pub/media/import** folder where zip folder can unzip programmatically.

```
 Images can be in jpeg/png. format. 
  How can I approach to achieve this.
```

Answer (score 2):

In your controller action upload file to temp folder after then run the following code

use this PHP manual for extract a zip file for more refference

```
http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php


<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('test.zip') === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('/my/destination/dir/');
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
?>
```